# Combo Box Column binded to Enum

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-mvc

How to define a Combo Column in Gridview which bind an Enum (as possibilities), but which has as default value coming from object coming from a List which bind the grid view?

The problem is coming from the bindlist which will display the different options in the combo should be a list of string... Kind of: 'None', 'True', 'False', 'Maybe'...

And the default value is coming from object.field1 which is coming from of List binded to the grid view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it!!

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
    {
        column.FieldName = "field_name";
        column.EditorProperties().ComboBox(p =>
        {
            p.DataSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Definition_of_Enum));
        });
    });
```

By Deveexpress support...